# What are the ways to express someone's condolences?

Tags: words, expressions

All is in the title, what are the ways to express someone's condolences when somebody died.
I know お気の毒に but is there something else?
What can/should you say to friends? To collegues? To bosses? etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some fixed expressions such as:

- ご愁傷さまです
- お悔やみ申し上げます

Both are formal, and can be used regardless of the relationship; you can say this to friends/colleagues/bosses. "ご愁傷さま" is sometimes used when nobody dies (e.g. ironically when somebody is disappointed) while "お悔やみ申し上げます" is almost always limited to the context of condolences, but both are perfectly fine. Additionally:

- ({at least originally} In Buddhism) ご冥福をお祈り[します/申し上げます]

---

お悔やみ（おくやみ） or 弔辞 is the translation for condolence, so if you need something more than fixed expressions, you can search with these words --- many people don't know what to say to somebody experiencing a great loss, and seek for guidance. Additionally, it is common to send a telegram of condolence ("弔電") for funerals (when one can't attend), and [expressions for these](https://www.ntt-east.co.jp/dmail/okuyami/) might also be worth reading.