# How do you replace 「お悔やみ」 in condolences to a Japanese Christian?

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances, formality, religion

In [Yosh's answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/24186/4547) to the question [What are the ways to express someone's condolences?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24185/4547), this [link](https://www.ntt-east.co.jp/dmail/okuyami/) states that Buddhist terms should not be used in expressing condolences to a Christian in Japanese:

> 故人がキリスト教徒の場合
>
> 仏教用語を使わないように注意しましょう。
>
> ※主な仏教用語
> **「お悔やみ」**　「冥福」　「成仏」　「供養」　「弔う」　「仏」　「僧」

If this is accurate, I've been looking at [this list of condolences](https://www.verycard.net/example/bunrei.php?b_keicho=2&b_cd=30) and [this one](http://www.jp-guide.net/super/okuyami_denpo/chouden.html), and I see very little that could be used. Almost all of the samples include 「お悔やみ」 and a phrase such as 「安らかにご永眠されますようお祈りいたします」 or 「故人のご冥福をお祈りいたします」, which could potentially be appropriate for a Christian recipient who is Roman Catholic but do not sound appropriate for a Protestant (Protestants differ theologically on what happens to a soul/body after death, but generally do not believe the departed souls need to be prayed for. In English-language Protestant condolences, it is common to express that you will pray for the family of the deceased in this difficult time).

I have been informed by a Japanese Congregationalist (a type of Protestant) that his father (who was a Congregational church pastor, 会衆派教会のキリスト教徒) just passed away.

How can I alter

> ご尊父様のご逝去を悼み、謹んで**お悔み**を申し上げます。
>
> ご遺族皆様のお気持ちを思いますと心が痛みます。皆様のために祈っています。

to make it appropriate for a Protestant recipient?

Comment: As a Protestant myself, I wouldn't on first glance think of お悔やみ as 仏教用語 - it would sound just fine to me. Still, not being a native speaker, it might have connotations I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

How about this [Christian version](https://www.verycard.net/example/bunrei_2.php?b_cd=54)?

These phrases don't include 「お悔やみ」　「冥福」　「成仏」　「供養」　「弔う」　「仏」　「僧」.